# Django 1.4 new project folder structure forces project prefixes?

Tags: django

Using django 1.4 and have seen that when you use `startproject` it now creates a folder within your project with the same name.

```
-myproject/
           manage.py
           myproject/
                    settings.py
                    urls.py
```

[Documented change here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py)

Previously for my urls I could input

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

But that no longer works. Am I now supposed to prefix this with project name? i.e.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
```

--
In my `urls.py` I'd import settings but now I have to prefix it with `from myproject import settings`.

I thought prefixing variables with the project name was against django standards as it breaks reuseability?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, prefix `ROOT_URLCONF` with your project name:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
```

You shouldn't import settings directly anyway (see [*Using settings in Python code*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)). Instead, use the following, which works for both the old and new project layouts.

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Answer (score 54):

I would just add that it forces you to use prefixes when you accces your main `myproject.urls`, but it doesn't force you either way for your apps.  You can choose to store apps either in the top-level folder:

```
myproject
|-- manage.py
|-- myproject
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
`-- polls
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    `-- views.py
```

This is the default when you use `python manage.py startapp polls`
In this case you'd use `from polls.models import Whatever`

Alternatively, you can:

```
mkdir myproject/polls
python manage.py startapp polls myproject/polls
```

And you'll get this:

```
myproject
|-- manage.py
`-- myproject
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- polls
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- tests.py
    |   `-- views.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- urls.py
    `-- wsgi.py
```

In which case you'll have to `from myproject.polls.models import Whatever`...

So the former is better for apps you think you might be able to re-use in other projects, and the latter is better for apps that are tightly coupled with other parts of your project.