# Why does my Django site on Heroku need different import paths?

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django 1.4 site that I've been developing locally (OS X 10.8.1). It works fine. But I'm now trying to set things up on Heroku, and it's failing to import modules from my apps.

The structure is like this:

```
manage.py
projectname/
    __init__.py
    appnameone/
    appnametwo/
    settings/
    static/
    wsgi.py
requirements.txt
```

In my settings, I'm including my own apps using the project name, like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'projectname.appnameone',
    'projectname.appnametwo',
    ...
)
```

And when I'm importing a module, I do it without the project name, eg:

```
from appnameone.models.model_name import ModelName
```

This works fine locally, but when I try and run anything (like `syncdb`) on Heroku, then I get an `ImportError` from the above line. It seems like it works if I add the projectname to import statements, like this:

```
from projectname.appnameone.models.model_name import ModelName
```

But that doesn't work on my local environment.

I guess it's something to do with paths, but I'm not sure what's up. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried including your apps without the precedent ``projectname``? like ``appnameone`` and not like ``projectname.appnameone`` in your ``settings.py``?

Comment: Good thinking, but that only gets me `ImportError appnameone: No module named appnameone` in `django/template/loaders/app_directories.py`.

Comment: Oh, right, you have your apps _inside_. Glad you figured out the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

When I thought that this didn't work in my local environment:

```
from projectname.appnameone.models.model_name import ModelName
```

I think I must have just run into some other problem. Because having been through and updated all of the imports of my apps to be prefixed with the project name, it now works in both my local environment and on Heroku.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10062871/250962) has a good explanation of the difference between putting your apps at the same level as your project (in which case imports don't need the project name prefix) and putting your apps *within* your project (in which case the project name prefix is needed).

It sounds like my local environment, as described in the question, shouldn't have been working, as my apps are within the project but I wasn't importing them as such. I'm guessing my Python Path here is very lax and was letting me get away with this when it shouldn't.

**UPDATE:** I realised the ultimate cause. During setup with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper I did something like this:

```
$ add2virtualenv ~/Projects/clientname/django-projectname/projectname
```

This added that to my PYTHONPATH, which made my environment very forgiving. On Heroku, this isn't the case (at least, not by default; maybe it's possible to tweak it). Once I'd removed that extra path from `lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_path_extensions.pth` within my virtualenv directory, then I started getting the same errors that I was getting on Heroku. Which means I can fix them better!